# result of one query table name of another and results in multiple csv outfiles

Tags: mysql

I am trying to finish one task little bit faster and I have two problems (hopefully possible to include in one question because both problems would appear in one query).

I would like to use result of one SQL query (which is multiple id's) as table names for another query (FROM ...? ).

Then final results (for each table) should be written in multiple .csv OUTFILE's instead of one that I have at the moment.

I have two queries ready, but I think Its not important for this question and this is why I skipped to post anything.

You may give me example on the simplest SELECT query.

Comment: Your question is not at all clear. Please properly define the scenario

Comment: what exactly isnt clear enough ? nothing ?

Comment: The scenario which you want to implement and how should the data be pipelined to other queries or is it a case of subqueries.

Comment: so result of one sql query is multiple id's like: 2261,2265,2232 etc. than I want to use this result in another query but as a table name. because in another database those id's are table names. the second query which will go in each table name named by id's will have its results written in multiple csv files. before, i had to manually write id as table name and then to run the query(second one), and its result was written in one csv file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use server-side prepared statements:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html

Here is an example that is hopefully helpful:

```
select @q:=concat("select count(*) from ", tbl_name) 
from my_db.my_tables where table_id = 3;
prepare s from @q;
execute s;
```

results in executing `select count(*) from` whatever the value of `tbl_name` was in `my_db.my_tables` for the `table_id` equal to 3.

To export the result to CSV you can do:

```
select @q:=concat("select count(*) from ", tbl_name, 
" into outfile '/tmp/data.csv' fields terminated by ','") 
from my_db.my_tables where table_id = 3;
```

To learn more about `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE`:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-into.html